# How to share a jupyter notebook with plotly charts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, plotly

Does anyone knows how should I share a `jupyter notebook` (with `python3`) that contains `plotly` made charts ? So far I use `github` to share notebooks, but the `plotly` charts just won't show up on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [Plotly Offline for iPython Notebooks](https://plot.ly/python/offline/). The link shows the syntax for creating charts. If you create the charts in offline mode, you can covert the notebook to html and share it with anyone. You would do this by:

1. Creating the charts with Plotly Offline
2. `cd` into your directory where the notebook is held
3. convert the notebook to a static html file by typing `ipython nbconvert [YOUR NOTEBOOK NAME].ipynb`

Comment: Where should I type ``ipython nbconvert ...`` ? inside the notebook or a cmd ?

Comment: type it at the cmd after you've cd'd to the proper directory

Comment: going to File > Download As > html worked just fine ! thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

If you use kyso.io (disclaimer: I founded kyso) you can share notebooks online easily and it supports plotly.

- Here is a plotly example: https://kyso.io/laura/plotly-example/

you can share a notebook using these commands

```
kyso create "some study title"
kyso push "a version message"
```